# How to add a local eth1 ethernet connection without losing external eth0?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ethernet, gateway

There are two Ethernet connections in the wall of the room. The first has an external IP address and is connected to computer C1, while the other has an internal (university network) address and is connect to computer C2:

```
(internet 1) ---- C1

(internet 2) ---- Switch ---- C2
```

I want to be able to log into C2 from an external IP address, by first logging into C1 and then doing `ssh 192...` to get to C2. So I want a second connection from C1 to the router like so:

```
(internet 1) ---- C1
                   |
(internet 2) ---- Switch ---- C2
```

C1 has two ethernet connections, `eth0` and `eth1`. `eth0` has the external IP address.

So I plugged `eth1` on C1 into the switch, but then I can no-longer access C1 externally.

If I do `ifdown eth1`, then connection via `eth0` from an external IP address becomes possible again after rebooting C1.

Connection from a local (192...) IP address is always possible, whether `eth1` is up or down.

The external IP is fixed while the local IP address is obtained via DHCP.

Maybe I'm missing key technical search terms because an internet search for a solution was unsuccessful. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, ifconfig information on C1 is copied below. Thank you.

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0D:D4:7A:31:E1:D6
      inet addr:145.18.73.25  Bcast:145.18.73.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fd80::ac8:7aff:fe31:e1d6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:358816 (350.4 KiB)  TX bytes:174963 (170.8 KiB)

eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0D:D4:7A:31:E1:D7
      inet addr:192.168.2.176  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fd80::ac8:7aff:fe31:e1d7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:10196 (9.9 KiB)  TX bytes:894 (894.0 b)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:7010 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7010 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1276612 (1.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1276612 (1.2 MiB)
```

---

Based on the kind comment from Ipor Sircer I looked into gateway information:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
145.18.72.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         145.18.73.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

$ ifup eth1
Determining IP information for eth1... done.

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
145.18.72.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1


$ cat /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth0
EVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=0d:d4:7a:31:e1:d6
USERCTL=no
IPADDR=145.18.73.25
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
DNS2=145.18.1.6
GATEWAY=145.18.73.254
DNS1=145.18.6.1

$ cat /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=no
USERCTL=no
HWADDR=0d:d4:7a:31:e1:d7
DNS1=192.168.2.1
PEERDNS=yes
```

I get the impression that eth1 is overwriting some route settings of eth0, but I'm not sure what I need to do next.

Comment: Look at your default route gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth1` there is another file at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`. Removing the `GATEWAY=192.168.2.1` line from that file followed by `ifup eth1` results in a working configuration. For reference, the entire file looks like:

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=no
USERCTL=no
HWADDR=0d:d4:7a:31:e1:d7
DNS1=192.168.2.1
PEERDNS=yes
```

Thank you to Ipor Sircer and dirkt for their help.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, your default route (0.0.0.0) changes from 145.18.73.254 at `eth0` to 192.168.2.1 at `eth1`. (BTW, the more modern way to get routes is `ip route` resp. `ip -6 route`.).

The gateway gets set when the DHCP client receives a `router` information via the DHCP protocol when `eth1` becomes active.

To prevent this from happening, you need a `dhclient.conf` (usually `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, may vary with distro) file with a modified `requst` stanza for `eth1` that doesn't include `router`. See `man dhclient` and `man dhclient.conf` for details.